# vb.net byte cannot be converted to string

Tags: vb.net

i have checked for answers on Stackoverflow before anyone says, and i am still puzzled, I am trying to upload an image i have saved using ms.Toarray() but i keep getting "byte -1 cannot be converted to string" etc, here is my code i am trying to use thanks

```
            header.AppendFormat("filename=""{0}""", IO.Path.GetFileName(ms.toarray()))
            header.AppendLine()
            header.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
            header.AppendLine()

            Dim headerbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString)
            Dim endboundarybytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbNewLine & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: What line is the error appearing on? I assume `Dim filebytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(ms.ToArray())`

Comment: sorry yes, it shows on all lines with ms.toarray()

Comment: All of the places you seem to be using ms.ToArray don;t want an array of Bytes passed they want the file name of a binary file with data in it.

Comment: see if i save the file first (obviously to disk) then use filepath it works perfect, however i dont want to save the file im just wanting to upload it (hence saving it to memorystream) do you have any way around this> / work how ive explained?

Comment: There is no point saving anything at all. ms.toArray() already IS the binary data after you loaded it from the PNG. So for example `Dim filebytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(ms.ToArray())` could be `Dim filebytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(ms)` . `IO.FileInfo(ms.toarray()).Length` could be `ms.Length`

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved the matter, however if it will make it better i will have a look into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File.ReadAllBytes` method expects a string, and would use that string as the name of a file that it would read. You can't use it to read from a stream.

You already have the byte array that you want from `ms.ToArray()` so you don't need to do anything more with it:

```
Dim filebytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
```

The `IO.FileInfo` method also expects a string, and would use it as a file name. You should get the `filebytes` array earlier in the code, so that you can use it to calculate the length:

```
req.ContentLength = headerbytes.Length + filebytes.Length + endboundarybytes.Length
```

Also, I see that you are saving the image twice to the memory stream, you should only do it once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I deleted the "Dim filebytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray()" from further down my code and replaced it at the top, it now works perfect.